# Difference between opencv_core.Mat vs opencv.core.Mat and how to convert to each other?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

What is the difference between the two?

org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.Mat

org.opencv.core.Mat

And how can they be converted to each other?

I thought javacpp is a wrapper around opencv and thought they both are the same. But not.

Comment: It is better to use OpenCV from its official site, which has a very nice and clean Java wrapper. In JavaCV you will find a lot of deprecated and duplicated codes which make it hard to know which one to use. So the OpenCV Java wrapper is very clean and also it has the newest added C++ plus functionality as well (up to date).

Comment: Use only `org.opencv.core.Mat` in your code and remove any imports involving `org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.Mat`

Comment: @BahramdunAdil The C/C++ API of OpenCV contains a lot of deprecated and duplicated code. This is unrelated to JavaCPP or JavaCV.

Comment: @SamuelAudet It is related to JavaCV, I before was using the JavaCV, there I found much many duplicated and deprecated codes which the same as this guy confused me which one to use, even you still can find IpImage in JavaCV, so the JavaCV wrapper needs a very deep clean up and better documentation. If there was not such problem which I mentioned, then this guy won't ask this question.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil It's JavaCPP's job to make C/C++ APIs usable from Java. Once it's gone from OpenCV, it will also be gone from JavaCV, so please make your request upstream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wrappers generated with JavaCPP are more complete, as explained on http://bytedeco.org/faq/:

> **How does it differ from wrappers in OpenCV, TensorFlow, etc?**
>
> [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) was designed for maximum performance and flexibility. It
>   strives to map as much of C++ as the Java language can reasonably
>   handle, offering a level of usability to native functionality
>   unmatched by any other solutions that we are aware of. It also
>   provides a common foundation, a set of basic classes, to increase the
>   interoperability between different native libraries on the Java
>   platform. Plus, its integration with standard tools such as Maven
>   facilitates development and deployment.

JavaCV bundles both APIs so we can use them together without problem. We can also easily convert between the two with [OpenCVFrameConverter](http://bytedeco.org/javacv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacv/OpenCVFrameConverter.html), for example:

```
OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat converter1 = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat();
OpenCVFrameConverter.ToOrgOpenCvCoreMat converter2 = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToOrgOpenCvCoreMat();
Mat mat = ...;
org.opencv.core.Mat cvmat = converter2.convert(converter1.convert(mat));
Mat mat2 = converter2.convert(converter1.convert(cvmat));
```

Comment: So, just to be clear, it is fine to use anything in "org.bytedeco.javacpp" so far, right. Had to ask cos the person above said to avoid using it. I find JavaCPP really useful and easy to understand. That aside, why are there two Mat versions? When to use which?

Comment: Wait! I realize that you have the same name as the project lead for JavaCPP project. XD

Comment: The developers of OpenCV prefer to have full control over their projects, but they don't understand the importance of Java. They would rather keep using their Python scripts since they are used to create the Python wrappers as well. It's also hard to make any significant contribution to the core project, but not impossible...